# Google Tag Manager Data Layer implementation and Magento Shop

Tags: magento, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, data-layer

I'm trying to connect Magento with Google Tag Manager, especially in order to track transactions and other e-commerce data in Google Analytics.

I installed this GTM [Magento extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-tag-manager-6455.html) which is useful to add the GTM snippet at the right place and the GTM connection does work, but as you can see below transaction data is undefined - as no data layer is declared before the GTM snippet :

```
utmwv:5.4.1
utms:68
utmn:238730863
utmhn:127.0.0.1
utmt:tran
utmtid:undefined
utmtst:undefined
utmtto:undefined
utmttx:undefined
utmtsp:undefined
utmtci:undefined
utmtrg:undefined
utmtco:undefined
utmcs:UTF-8
utmsr:1280x800
utmvp:842x599
utmsc:24-bit
utmul:en-us
utmje:1
utmfl:11.7 r700
utmdt:Magento Commerce
utmhid:1296887870
utmr:0
utmp:/magento/index.php/checkout/onepage/success/
...
```

What I need now is to build and declare the GTM data layer before the GTM snippet into the /checkout/onepage/success page. Problem is I'm very new to Magento and I have no idea how to do this and I am looking for some help or tutorial dedicated to this kind of task.

Comment: Whats the question? Do you want a link to a Magento tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using magento and you want to implement conversion tracking or ecommerce tracking then it is not required to install any extension . you can directly implement GTM container code in Footer either Magento admin or using FTP.

Follow this link to get Total value http://www.notesonclick.com/blog/add-adwords-conversion-tracking-on-magento-with-conversion-value/

And add  this code in success.phtml

```html
<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId()); 
$subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();
$gtotal = $order->getGrandTotal();

?> 
<script>
  var dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[];
  dataLayer.push({'event':'order-placed','orderTotal':<?php echo $gtotal;?>,'orderSubTotal':<?php echo $subtotal;?>});
  </script>
```

and for ecommerce Tracking Follow http://www.notesonclick.com/blog/add-google-analytics-ecommerce-tracking-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Why not include the GTM snippet within the global template and trigger a given tag based on the URI?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Aromicon extension for Universal Analytics which has the base eCommerce datalayer variables already created and ready to use out of the box.